# Mongodb aggregate need help in one query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I am trying to find total occurrence with its percentage with total occurrence

For example :

we have one user table with below collection structure

```
user : [
      {
          email : A@abc.com,
          eyeColor: blue, 
      },
       {
          email : B@abc.com,
          eyeColor: brown, 
      },
       {
          email : C@abc.com,
          eyeColor: blue, 
      },
       {
          email : D@abc.com,
          eyeColor: red, 
      },
       {
          email : E@abc.com,
          eyeColor: blue, 
      }
]
```

Now I can get total number of occurrences of eye colors using aggregate query

```
db.users.aggregate([$group : [_id: “$eyeColor”,total : {$sum : 1}]  
])
```

I need output something like below

```
[{ "_id" : blue, "count" : 3 },{ "_id" : red, "count" : 1 },{ "_id" : brown, "count" : 1 }]
```

Now what I am trying to get I need one more field in each object in above output called percentageOccupied ( how many % eye color from total occurrences) by using formula `(occurrence / total_occurrence) * 100`

For example by considering aggregate output
 we have 3 blue color so I need something like below

```
[{ "_id" : blue, "count" : 3, percentage: 60 },{ "_id" : red, "count" : 1, percentage: 20 },{ "_id" : brown, "count" : 1, percentage: 20 }, total : 5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `$facet`, with facet you can do multiple operation on a same document on different fields

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $facet : {
        "total" : [{$count : "eyeColor"}],
        "data" : [{$group : {_id : "$eyeColor", count : {$sum : 1}}}]
    }},
    {$unwind : "$data"},
    {$addFields : {"data.percentage" : {$multiply : [{$divide : ["$data.count", {$arrayElemAt : ["$total.eyeColor", 0]}]}, 100]}}},
    {$replaceRoot : {newRoot : "$data"}}    
]).pretty()
```

Comment: getting error of Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$facet'

Comment: Okay I am using version 3.2 this filed is in 3.4

Answer (score 2):

You can add another `$group` stage to calculate the count and `$addFields` to output the percentage value

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {"$group":{"_id":null,"total":{"$sum":1},"eyeColor":{"$push":"$eyeColor"}}},
  {"$unwind":"$eyeColor"},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$eyeColor","total":{"$first":"$total"},"occurrence":{"$sum":1}}},
  {"$project":{"percentage":{"$multiply":[{"$divide":["$occurrence","$total"]},100]}, "total":1}}
])
```

Comment: getting error of Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'

Comment: Okay I am using version 3.2 this filed is in 3.4

Comment: replace `$addFields` with `$project`. Updated answer.